# Xcode running iOS App debug session, cannot detect Memory usage

Tags: xcode

Using Xcode 6.4, when running iOS App debug session on iPhone 6 (not simulator), memory usage is claimed to be 0 bytes, which is impossible (CPU usage is normal).

[image: Screenshot of Xcode]

How can I fix it?

I re-run the debug session, still the same.

Comment: which iOS version is on your iPhone?

Comment: Did you try to reboot the phone and restart Xcode ?

Comment: Same after reboot phone & restarted Xcode.